# How to make CustomAction not to abort the installation instead it will show a simple error message?

Tags: wix, custom-action

This is my code..

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CA_ErrOptionsNotSelected"><![CDATA[OPTION1_SELECTED <> "1" AND OPTION2_SELECTED <> "1"]]></Publish>
    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CA_ErrAllOptionsSelected">OPTION1_SELECTED = "1" AND OPTION2_SELECTED = "1"</Publish>
</Control>

<CustomAction Id="CA_ErrOptionsNotSelected" Error="Please select any one option." />
<CustomAction Id="CA_ErrAllOptionsSelected" Error="You cannot select all options. Please select only one option." />
```

While the user clicks the Next button in a dialog, I want to display a simple error message if the user either does not select any option or selects all the options in the dialog.

I don't want to abort the installation but to show the user an error message and continue with the installation.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're in the UI so in general you set one or more properties when the correct things are present. Your button click can run multiple actions, such as validating the input, then setting a property that says the input is ok, and then enable/disable the Next button so the user cannot advance, then putting an error message into some area of the dialog and making it visible, or a DoAction Event that calls Message.